# Trigonometry: Find the smallest Angles

Tags: trigonometry

Calculate the measure of the smallest angle in the triangle formed by the points A (-2, -3), B(2, 5) and C(4, 1).

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematics Stack Exchange. Homework questions are welcome here, but they must show sufficient effort. What have you tried to solve this problem so far?

Comment: "The" smallest angle will be opposite the smallest side. Now use the Cosine Law as suggested in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Use the distance formula to get the lengths of the three sides and then apply the Law of Cosines.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  do you know the [cosine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_rule)?  Can you apply it here?